# Set property for relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and working on the movielens dataset. The graph that I am trying to create is as follows: `(User{userID,Gender,Age,Occupation})-[WATCHED{Rating}]->(Movie{Title,Genres})`, where `userID,Gender,Age,Occupation` are properties of user, `Rating` is a property of `WATCHED` relationship and `Title,Genres` are properties of `Movie`.

My data looks like this:

```
UserID;Gender;Age;Occupation;MovieID;Ratings;Title;Genres
4;M;45;7;3468,1210,2951,1214,1036,260,2028,480,1196;5,3,4,4,4,5,5,4,2;Star Wars- Episode IV - A New Hope (1977),Jurassic Park (1993),Die Hard (1988),E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982),Star Wars- Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980),Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981),Good The Bad and The Ugly The (1966),Star Wars- Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983),Alien (1979);Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi,Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi,Action|Thriller,Childrens|Drama|Fantasy
```

The query I used to create the user and movie nodes is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///user_movie_info_user-rating.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH line,SPLIT(line.MovieID, ",") AS Movie,SPLIT(line.Title, ",") AS Title,SPLIT(line.Genres, ",") AS Genres
MERGE (u:User { uID:TOINTEGER(line.UserID),gender:line.Gender,age: TOINTEGER(line.Age),occupation:TOINTEGER(line.Occupation)})
WITH Movie,Title,Genres
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(Movie)-1) as j
MERGE (m:Movie {MovieID:TOINTEGER(Movie[j]),Title:Title[j],Genre:Genres[j]})
```

The query to create relationship between nodes is:

```
MATCH (m:Movie),(u:User) WHERE u.uID=1 AND m.MovieID in [3468,1210,2951,1214,1036,260,2028,480,1196] CREATE (u)-[s:WATCHED]->(m) RETURN type(s)
```

However, I am not sure how to add the ratings to the `WATCHED` relationship. I tried this

`MATCH p=(u:User)-[r:WATCHED]->(m:Movie) WHERE u.uID=1 AND m.MovieID=1193 SET r.Rating=[5]`,

but this needs to be run for each and every movie. Is there a better way (something like below)?

`MATCH p=(u:User)-[r:WATCHED]->(m:Movie) WHERE u.uID=1 AND m.MovieID IN [1193,1210,2951] SET r.Rating IN [5,3,4]`

Comment: @blackus - Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the Ratings field like the others, pass each user node along, and create the relationship at the same time as creating the movie nodes

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///user_movie_info_user-rating.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH line,
   SPLIT(line.MovieID, ",") AS Movie,
   SPLIT(line.Title, ",") AS Title,
   SPLIT(line.Genres, "|") AS Genres,
   SPLIT(line.Ratings, ",") AS Ratings

MERGE (u:User { uID:TOINTEGER(line.UserID),gender:line.Gender,age: TOINTEGER(line.Age),occupation:TOINTEGER(line.Occupation)})
WITH Movie,Title,Genres,Ratings, u

UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(Movie)-1) as j
MERGE (m:Movie {MovieID:TOINTEGER(Movie[j]),Title:Title[j],Genre:Genres[j]})
CREATE (u)-[:WATCHED{Rating:Ratings[j]}]->(m)
```